# Caption on top and bottom for two subfigures

Tags: captions, subfloats, subfig

using subfig package is there any possibility to show a caption of first sub figure on top and for the other one at the bottom.

I am using the below code for displaying the two subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
                \subfloat[Caption 1]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{1.png}} \\
                \subfloat[Caption 2]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{2.png}}
        \caption{Figure Description}\label{foo}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No.  At least none of the options listed on pages 8-9 of the manual allow captions on top.  OTOH, you could easily create your own version using a minipage and \savebox.

Comment: Since these are not side by side, why even bother with \subfloats?  Just use \subcaption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was easier to create two commands than add a second optional argument.  If the use of `top` and `bottom` is counter-intuitive to you, feel free to rename them.

BTW, all `position=top` does is reverse `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newsavebox{\subfloatbox}

\newcommand{\topfloat}[2][\empty]% #1 = caption, #2=image
 {\savebox\subfloatbox{#2}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\wd\subfloatbox}
    \usebox\subfloatbox
    \subcaption{#1}
  \end{minipage}}

\newcommand{\bottomfloat}[2][\empty]% #1 = caption, #2=image
 {\savebox\subfloatbox{#2}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\wd\subfloatbox}
    \captionsetup{position=top}%
    \subcaption{#1}
    \usebox\subfloatbox
  \end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
                \bottomfloat[Caption 1]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{1.png}} \\
                \topfloat[Caption 2]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{2.png}}
        \caption{Figure Description}\label{foo}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

An even simpler solution.  Note that `\subcaption` has to be inside a group or it will cause a permanent change to `\@captype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        {\captionsetup{position=top}
            \subcaption{Caption 2}
            \includegraphics[width=7cm]{1.png}}\\
        {\includegraphics[width=7cm]{2.png}
            \subcaption{Caption 1}}
        \caption{Figure Description}\label{foo}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but in your answer the captions are getting created between two figures. I want the Caption 1 to be on top of sub-figure.

Comment: Presto chango, she is done!